# How to get current url from browser

Tags: python, odoo

I need to get current url from browser and extract the name of the opened model.
I have 3 models: audit, dysfunction and action, action has a selection field containing 2 choices: audit or dysfunction. So when I create an action, I can choose by myself, but when I create an audit, then in the audit form create an action, I want the selection field to take 'audit' as type from the first.
I noticed that when we enter the action form from the audit form the URL still holds the name of the first model which is 'audit'. Audit model has a many2many relation with action model. I wrote this line in the **init** function:

```
print (self.env._current_browser()._current_page)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute '_current_browser'
```

I alse tried this code:

```
    import os.path
    from urlparse import urlparse,parse_qs
    print 'hello update'
    url = os.environ["REQUEST_URI"] 
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url) 
    print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['model']
```

It gives me this error:

```
KeyError: 'REQUEST_URI'
```

I also tried this code:

```
from openerp import http

print http.request.httprequest.full_path
```

It gives me this:

```
/web/dataset/call_kw/action/create?
```

But I want it to return this url:

```
http://localhost:8069/web?#id=10&view_type=form&model=audit&menu_id=201&action=221
```

I'm working with python 2.7, odoo 8, windows 7.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide detailed code. What is self supposed to be e.g.?

Comment: @Tesssnim Look here ackoverflow.com/questions/14468862/how-to-get-current-url-in-python-web-page

Comment: @RichardRublev I tried it before It gives me this error: 
    File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\addons\action\action.py", line 63, in _get_origin
    url = os.environ["REQUEST_URI"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'REQUEST_URI'

Comment: @Tessnim You are using Windows?

Comment: @RichardRublev Yes I am

Comment: @rocksteady self references the current active action model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current path using httprequest

```
from openerp import http

print http.request.httprequest.full_path
```

But you should not call it in **init** method, AFAIK **init** is going to be called once at startup.

Edit:

If what you need is to pass an info from a model to another, I suggest you passing the value through context.

Say the `audit` has a many2one relation to `action` model.

```
class audit(models.Model):

    _name = "audit"

    action = fields.Many2one('action', string="Action")
```

Pass the context on your view :

```
<field name="action" context="{'from':'This is from audit model'}"/>
```

and when you're at `action` model you can call the context using this method:

```
self._context.get('from', False)
```

It doesn't have to be a field to pass context, you can do it in button too.

Comment: It gives me this url:
/web/dataset/call_kw/action/create?
I want him to return this: http://localhost:8069/web?#id=10&view_type=form&model=audit&menu_id=221&action=229

Answer (score 0):

I found this today:

I just need to add this attribute to the action field inside of audit form

```
context="{'default_origin':'audit'}"
```

Noting that inside of the action model I have:

```
origin = fields.Selection([
                               ('audit', 'Audit'),
                               ('nonconformity', 'nonConformity'),                
                               ('dysfunction', 'Dysfunction')])
```